# What are the effects of splash weapons and other non-magical sources of energy damage on golems?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, damage-types

Golems are, with very scarce exceptions, immune to spells, except for a few that affect them normally or have different effects (an iron golem takes damage from rusting spells, an ice golem takes full damage from fire and is repaired by cold damage).

Most of the time, energy damage (fire, cold, acid, electric and sonic) is magic and thus out of the question when dealing with a golem, but some ways exist to deal energy damage that aren't, splash weapons are one of them.

What would happen if my character threw an acid vial or an alchemist's fire on a iron golem ? Are there any general rules about what type of energy damage a golem resists, even from a non-magical source ?

Answer (score 10):

As the source of the acid is non magical it would not be subject to the Golem's magic immunity and would deal its usual 1d6 damage. It is also worth noting that the golem is only immune to magic effects that allow spell resistance. Almost any acid spell does not allow spell resistance and would therefore work normally.